# unknown words in include php

Tags: php, include

So I have this part of code where I count all items files in a directory. after that I want to include all files he counted.

```
<?php 
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $Number = 0; 
    $dir = 'includes/cubes/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $Number++;
        }
    }

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= Number ; $i++){
  include("includes/cubes/cube{$i}.php");
}
?>
```

for example I have filenames like:

- cube1-RubiksCube
- cube2-ProfessorCube

etc.

So when I include files like cube1.php it goes alright but I want to have that extra text after the "-" removed.

so it's no problem when I have it named like cube1-test.php

That text can be anything so I need something that replaces everything what comes after the "-"

Comment: Why are there two different folders with distinct naming schemes anyway? Why not just `glob("cubes/c*.php`)` and map that without a numeric `for` loop?

Comment: So I can arrange them from old to new, so i give my oldest like cube1someName.php and every newer one gets like cube2-someName.php and so on @mario

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preg_replace` function and replace the -... with nothing.

```
$string = "cube1-RubiksCube";
$string = preg_replace("/\-(.*?)$/", "", $string);
echo $string; // returns "cube1"
```